# Excel SendKeys Interaction with Internet Explorer

Tags: vba, excel, internet-explorer

The following Excel VBA code successfully inserts the desired text into the Google webpage.  However, if the "Set Wss" line is removed and the "Wss.SendKeys" commands are replaced with "Application.Senkeys" the code fails to insert the text.  Why is this?  What does "CreateObject("WScript.Shell")" do that leads to successful text insertion onto the webpage?

```
Sub Macro2()
Set Wss = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")

Set ie = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")

With ie
    .Visible = True
    .Navigate "https://www.google.com/"
    .Top = 0
    .Left = 0
    .Height = 1025
    .Width = 1925

' Loop until the page is fully loaded
        Do Until Not ie.Busy And ie.ReadyState = 4
            DoEvents
        Loop
        Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("0:00:05"))
    End With

' Use SendKeys to insert text
    Wss.SendKeys "this"
    Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("0:00:01"))
    Wss.SendKeys " is a"
    Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("0:00:01"))
    Wss.SendKeys " test"
    Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("0:00:01"))
End Sub
```

Comment: What is the version of your Excel?

Comment: @Tehscript Excel 2002 and IE 11

Comment: Before you do your first `SendKeys`  to IE, add `AppActivate "Unique title"` where "Unique Title" is (I believe) what the IE Window will have across the main top bar. (Or maybe `AppActivate "Internet Explorer"`  would work)

Comment: As far as I know Excel 2002 doesn't support Sendkeys. If you try it in a later version, you will see that all three of `Sendkeys`, `Application.Sendkeys` and `CreateObject("WScript.Shell").Sendkeys` is functioning.